# Cannot import public keys to Azure key vault

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

I am trying to import public keys to Azure key vault via portal, although Azure says the file is uploaded successfully, I cannot see the imported key!

I am uploading the .pem public key file

Comment: Could you include more details like what you tried by editing your question?

Comment: Could you try provide some screenshots (Be careful to not include sensitive information). Could it be an RBAC issue that you're not allowed to see your own keys?

Comment: They RBAC is set to Vault owner. No screenshots needed as nothing appears!